# "colcon_core.package_augmentation" Error When Building Python Package With Colcon in ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, build, colcon, python3

I get the following error when trying to build my python package with Colcon build

```
    [0.235s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.package_augmentation:Exception in package augmentation extension 'python':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/package_augmentation/__init__.py", line 97, in augment_packages
    retval = extension.augment_packages(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_installed_package_information/package_augmentation/python.py", line 44, in augment_packages
    dist = next(iter(dists))
StopIteration
```

What could be the reason for this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My error went away after I ran the following commands:

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade

Running these commands updated the following packages which fixed my issue:

- python3-colcon-cd
- python3-colcon-core
- python3-colcon-installed-package-information

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as you and I managed to somewhat fix it.

To fix it I built with colcon after a clean terminal -- as in **without** any **sources** to any ros2 **installations** -- and got no warning/error messages.

I'm now curious as to why sourcing ROS2 Humble at `/opt/ros/<ros_distro>/setup.bash` is giving this error when colcon building.

Edit:
Seems like as of today (18-03-2024) the colcon packages have been updated and this issue has been fixed, even when sourcing the ros2 distros. Case closed.

I'm still curious what went wrong tho...

Comment: It is great that you found a solution. However, please do not ask follow up questions in your answers posts. If you have a new question, then please hit the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. The answers section is not where questions should be asked. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your input, @Greenonline. Just to clarify, my response was more of a thought than a question. Moving forward, it might help to distinguish between thoughts and inquiries. Thank you for your understanding.